# How to install ubuntu 14.04 inside window 7 using wubi without internet?

Tags: 14.04

Although i have same release of ubuntu and wubi and are in same directoy. But also while installing it automatically connects to internet and starts downloading ubuntu. i have already downloaded ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso of 987MB. Should i have to download other applications like metalink or something so that while installing internet will not be required? Please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got wubi from but please be aware that wubi is now basically officially dead, and burning a disk or usb and installing normally is really recommended above trying to use something that may variably let you install from inside windows with more or less the same interface but far lower success rate.

Comment: i tried making usb bootable, but during installation there occured error. Choosing set-up alongside windows, i got continue option and after clicking in continue, my computer got restarted and and came again restart to continue option while installing ubuntu 14.04 alongside win 7.